# Dual band WiFi stick

Tags: wifi

I am looking for a dual band wifi stick for the Raspberry Pi.
Which stick does work on the Pi, what drivers are required?

Alternative would be a stick only operating in the 5Ghz band.

Comment: Be careful with your wording of questions like this, as they may be interpreted as shopping, off limits per the FAQ.

Answer (score 2):

Indirect search for such device can be done by looking for driver which supports 802.11a (PHY MODE; working in 5GHz) and USB on this site http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers .

Like http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/carl9170 (802.11n draft only) . Please note that it doesn't guarantee that it will work, but at least you have place to start with. Also I would recommend to read up on particular driver as feature supported differer greatly from driver to driver. But for the basic setup (as AP client) you are probably safe, as long as you don't worry too much about speed.